# Could ZF system prove that 2ω is a set?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

ω is a set could be proved in ZF system by axiom of infinity and axiom of separation. Could 2ω, that is, ω + n when n tends to infinite, is a set be proved in ZF system?

The axiom of infinity guarantees that there is at least one inductive set. But it doesn't guarantee that there are more than one inductive set. ω is an inductive set. Then the axiom of infinity cannot guarantee that there is other inductive set.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, $2\cdot\omega=\omega$, and $\omega+\omega=\omega\cdot2$. It's confusing, yes.

Secondly, yes, $\sf ZF$ *can* prove that $\omega+\omega$ is a set because it has the Replacement axiom schema. This means that if we define a function (e.g. mapping each element of $\omega$ to $\omega+n$), then the range of that function---when restricted to a set---is also a set.

More to the point, $\varphi(x,y)$ is defined as if $x\in\omega$, then $y=\omega+n$ defines a function when considering the domain $\omega$. Therefore the range of $\varphi$ when applied to $\omega$ is itself a set. This is $\{\omega+n\mid n\in\omega\}$. Taking the union of this set will give us exactly $\omega+\omega$, and I'll leave you to figure out why is that.

Without Replacement, though, you cannot prove the existence of $\omega\cdot2$, because $V_{\omega+\omega}$ satisfies all the axioms of $\sf ZF$ except Replacement, and there $\omega+\omega$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you Asaf Karagila. So, we need axiom of replacement to prove ω⋅2 is a set. We cannot prove ω⋅2 is a set without Replacement.

Comment: @user49413 That is correct. (Note that replacement is extremely powerful - it lets us construct uncountable ordinals too! Exercise: use Replacement to show that for every ordinal $\alpha$, there is an ordinal $\beta$ which is not in bjiection with $\alpha$. And we can go well beyond this. It seems your question implicitly assumes that choice plays a role in the construction of large ordinals, but this is false; and this statement can be formalized and proved by looking at Godel's $L$.)